# Filters don't work in Non-nested aggregation on nested fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, nested, aggregation

I have following ES mapping (using ES 5.7.6)

```
{
"properties": {
    "machine": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "networkInterface": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "macAddress": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields":{
                       "raw":{
                          "type":"keyword"
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I need the following -
Get the count of machines (parent document) for the nested field terms, with a filter on nested fields.**

To achieve it, I am building a filtered, non-nested aggregation on networkInterface.name.
But the filter does not seem to apply. THe terms returned include those which do not match the filter.

Please help me understand why is this behaviour and also, if there is a way to achieve the requirement in ES.
**I have tried following things -**

1. Non-nested filtered terms aggregation on 'networkInterface.name' This has nested filter.

```
"aggregations": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "query": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "networkInterface.name.raw": "Intel(R) 12345L"
                                    }
                                },
                                "path": "networkInterface",
                                "ignore_unmapped": false,
                                "score_mode": "none",
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "interfaceNames": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "networkInterface.name.raw",
                        "size": 1000,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [
                            {
                                "_count": "desc"
                            },
                            {
                                "_term": "asc"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Non-nested filtered terms aggregation on 'networkInterface.name' This has non-nested filter.

```
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "networkInterface.name.raw": "Intel(R) 12345L"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                    "boost": 1.0
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "interfaceNames": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "networkInterface.name.raw",
                        "size": 1000,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [
                            {
                                "_count": "desc"
                            },
                            {
                                "_term": "asc"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Both return the same results. I have only posted the "aggregation" part of the whole query, the "query" is the same in both above cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running non-nested aggregation, the nested context is lost and the filters have no effect on the aggregation buckets. This conclusion is based on trying out the multiple queries.